# How to connect to an oracle database in android?

Tags: java, android, oracle, ojdbc

I have an oracle database, i need to access to the info but i can't. I have imported the OJDBC6 driver, I created the class:

```
public class JDBC_ORA    {
     static String userName="XXX";
     static String password="X";
     static String server="192.168.X.X";

     public Connection con;

     public void conexion() {        
         try {          
             Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
             con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:" + userName + "/" + password+ "@"+server);            

         } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (SQLException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } 
     }


     public void cerrar (Connection con) {
         try {
             con.close();
         } catch (SQLException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();

         }
     }
}
```

And i call it in the mainactivity:

```
 JDBC_ORA ora_con = new JDBC_ORA();   
    ora_con.conexion();
    try {
        Statement stmt = ora_con.con.createStatement();
        rset = stmt.executeQuery("select * from asdf where cid='"+ var + "'" );
        while (rset.next())
        {
            System.out.println(blablablabla);
            ora_con.con.commit();
        }
        stmt.close();
        ora_con.cerrar(ora_con.con);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And always get this errors

```
Could not find class 'oracle.security.pki.OraclePKIProvider', referenced from method oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.<clinit>

Could not find class 'javax.management.MBeanServer', referenced from method oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.registerMBeans
```

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2):

Don't.  If you do this, you have to put your password in the app.  That means your database is totally insecure, and can be accessed by anyone with a copy of the app and 5 minutes to decompile it.  Instead, use a webservice that sits between your app and the database.  That way you never need the password to leave your machines.

Comment: in the password string i put it and the connection in my java programs are well

Comment: @marcss:  the phone app calls a service to get the data.  The service lives on a back-end server, and only the server knows how to connect to your database.  The server is not accessible by the outside world, other than through the service interface.  Note that this also supports changing the database without having to change the phone app, as long as the interface between the phone app and the service doesn't change.

Comment: But i don't want this. I want to connect only in my company and i need to connect by JDBC to take the info

Comment: Then tell your company why they need to do it another way.  Trust me, your company does NOT want to be this insecure.  JDBC is the wrong way for anything on a mobile device or client machine.

Comment: @marss:  that's a huge assumption and security risk.  Suppose a user is at a coffee shop using free, unsecured WiFi and the user accidentally opens the app?  Your app will broadcast connection attempts that anybody watching can see.  And believe me, there is ALWAYS somebody watching.

Comment: ans what's the best way to take the info from a oracle database? and how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

The best practice will be using a web-service written in Java,.Net, PHP, etc.. Then you need to connect your application with that web-service you created. The other way is to use [Oracle Database Mobile Server](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/database-mobile-server/overview/index.html).

You could find how to create web-service easily on google.